# I want to disable the cancel button in CFiledialog

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog, filedialog

I want to disable the cancel button in CFiledialog.

How can I do it?

Is there any way other than creating a new one using Cdialog?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: [EnableWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enablewindow) can disable mouse and keyboard input. Handling [WM_GETDLGCODE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/wm-getdlgcode) allows you to intercept the ESC key. [Other tricks with WM_GETDLGCODE](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031126-00/?p=41703) explains how.

Comment: Something along the lines of `GetDlgItem(IDCANCEL)->EnableWindow(FALSE)`.

Comment: hi @AndrewTruckle. How can I get Cfiledialog's IDCANCEL?

Comment: When I Googled your question it said: dialogvar.GetParent()->GetDlgItem(IDCANCEL)-m ...  I have not tested this.

Comment: The [explorer-style control identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/open-and-save-as-dialog-boxes#explorer-style-control-identifiers) are documented. That still leaves the question: What, if a user confused by the inability to click cancel simply closes the dialog?